# Is there an event for the TabControl that fires right before content is shown?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

Currently I'm using `TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp` to process operations like focusing on a textbox etc when a user has selected a tab to be shown.  The problem with this is the operation is taking place well after the tab has been changed and makes it very obvious and ugly looking when various task like changing focus to another textbox then selecting all the text in that box.

I tried the `TabControl_SelectionChanged` event but it seems to allow me to set focus before something else steels that focus.  In the end my target does not have focus.

Question: Is there another event I can use that comes after `TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp` and before `TabControl_SelectionChanged`?

Comment: Did not test but maybe `<TabItem Selector.Selected="TabItem_Selected">` is raised earlier.

Comment: Just gave it a shot and the order of events are `TabItem_Selected` then `TabControl_SelectionChanged` then `TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp`.

Comment: Also you could give a try to PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp.

Comment: Or Binding and FocusManager? #JustSaying